# check and uncheck all the nodes of the tree view in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, tabcontrol

I have the tree view in my windows application and in the tree view with the checkboxes and I have the Some "parent nodes" and some "child nodes" and i want to CHECK AND UNCHECK  the parent and child nodes at a time on clicking the "Check All" and "Uncheck All" button... How should i do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void CheckAllNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = true;
        CheckChildren(node, true);
    }
}

public void UncheckAllNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = false;
        CheckChildren(node, false);
    }
}

private void CheckChildren(TreeNode rootNode, bool isChecked)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
    {
        CheckChildren(node, isChecked);
        node.Checked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

Edit: Check branches to tick/untick all child nodes:

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    CheckChildren(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
private void CheckUncheckTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection trNodeCollection, bool isCheck)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode trNode in trNodeCollection)
            {
                trNode.Checked = isCheck;
                if (trNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    CheckUncheckTreeNode(trNode.Nodes, isCheck);
            }
        }
```

Pass `treeView.Nodes` to this function like `CheckUncheckTreeNode(trView.Nodes, true);` in button click event for checking all nodes. To uncheck all do `CheckUncheckTreeNode(trView.Nodes, false);`.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION:

```
Button_Click() {
    CheckUncheckTreeNode(YourTreeView.Nodes, false);
}

private void CheckUncheckTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection trNodeCollection, bool isCheck) {
    foreach (TreeNode trNode in trNodeCollection) {
        trNode.Checked = isCheck;
        if (trNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            CheckUncheckTreeNode(trNode.ChildNodes, isCheck);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question was asked and answered over a year ago. How does your answer provide new information that hasn't been covered by the previous respondents?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Checked)
        {
            UncheckNodes(treeView1.Nodes,e.Node);
        }

    }

    private void UncheckNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes, TreeNode except)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node != except) node.Checked = false;
            UncheckNodes(node.Nodes, except);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this WITHOUT recursion. put this code in a Button:

```
foreach (TreeNode Node in TreeNodeInUI.Nodes)
{
    Node.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I stumbled upon a similar issue I found a neat and simple solution. Yes, it's 8 years later, but maybe someone can make use of this.

Whenever a TreeNode is checked, store this TreeNode in a List. When you need to uncheck all nodes, loop the List and uncheck the nodes. This way you only iterate affected nodes.

Example:

---

**Store TreeNodes in a List after check**

```
public List<TreeNode> checkedNodes;

private void treeView1_afterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
    if(node.checked) {
        checkedNodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

**Iterate only checked nodes to uncheck all**

```
public void UncheckAllNodes()
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in checkedNodes)
    {
        node.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

This is still missing a removal when unchecking a checkbox, but you get the idea.

Comment: Your checkedNodes list isn't initialized.  Why are you looping in the AfterCheck event?  You keep adding the same checked nodes over and over again.  You don't need to, based on what you are trying to do.  Also, you are only capturing root level nodes, not child nodes.  Use the TreeViewEventArgs to only examine the node being checked.